# Почему не выполняется регламентное задание 1С?

Tags: 1с

Я создал регламентное задание в конфигураторе, подключил процедуру (ниже), включил `Использование` и `Предопределенное`, в расписании сделал `Выполнять: каждый день; с 1:00:00 по 23:00:00 каждые 5 секунд`. Но почему-то при открытии режима `Предприятие` задание не выполняется каждые 5 секунд. Как это можно исправить?

```
&НаСервере
Процедура Выгрузить() Экспорт
    НовоеВремя = Формат(ТекущаяДата(), "ДФ='ЧЧммсс'");
    Файл = Новый ЗаписьТекста("C:\Projects\" + НовоеВремя + ".txt");
    Файл.ЗаписатьСтроку(НовоеВремя);
    Файл.Закрыть();
    Сообщить(НовоеВремя);
КонецПроцедуры
```

В `Предприятии` в настройке регламентных заданий, у задания `Состояние` и `Дата окончания` почему-то не определены.

Comment: База файловая или серверная?

Comment: @Sagittarius не знаю, просто скачал учебную версию 1С с учебной базой, сейчас посмотрю какая

Comment: @Sagittarius видимо серверная, так как если заменить `&НаСервере` на `&НаКлиенте`, то вылетает ошибка при ручном запуске регламентного задания

Comment: Нет, директивы определяют, где будет выполнятся код. Файловая - база расположена в папке. Серверная - база развернута на сервере баз данных и объявлена через сервер приложений 1с(службу). Если у вас учебная - 99% файловый вариант.

Comment: @kio согласен, значит база файловая

Comment: Пользователь указан у рег. задания?

Comment: @Sagittarius пробовал указывать и не указывать - оба варианта не работают

Comment: Попробуй через [эту консоль](https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/3752/hdoc) запустить

Comment: В файловой базе рег. задания будут работать, если только есть клиентский сеанс. То есть, если закрыть режим предприятия, то автоматом задания не запустятся. Такое только в серверных работает.

Comment: @Sagittarius да, но почему-то при открытом режиме предприятия тоже не работают, сейчас разбираюсь с консолью, может поможет

Comment: Почитай про учебную версию, у неё же порезанный функционал! Может из-за этого и не работае)))

Answer (score 1):

Цитата из интернета:

Настройка регламентных заданий в файловом режиме работы 1С
В файловом режиме настройка таких заданий несколько труднее. Для такого задания должна быть запущена отдельная сессия программы 1С. Зачастую это решается заведением «технического» пользователя, чей сеанс всегда запущен.

В файловом режиме инициализация регламентного задания происходит при запуске метода `ВыполнитьОбработкуЗаданий()`

Для определенного пользователя можно настроить запуск этого метод, используя другой метод  —

`ПодключитьОбработчикОжидания(<ИмяПроцедуры>, <Интервал>, <Однократно>)`

Где:

Имя процедуры — имя процедуры, подключаемой в качестве обработчика ожидания. Имя экспортируемой процедуры модуля управляемого приложения (модуля обычного приложения) или глобального общего модуля. Процедура должна располагаться на клиенте.

Интервал — период между выполнениями операций в секундах.

Однократно — как выполнять задание, один раз или нет.